# Connect Neo4J on an existing Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, import, neo4j

I'm a Neo4j new user and I played around with the webadmin interface of Neo4j to create small databases and simple queries in Cypher. Now I want to use Neo4J to create a graph with my existing database. It's a postgresql database with millions of entries with the same structure (Neo4J is very adapted to represent these data). My question is how to import these data ? What is the easiest way to do that ? I already saw that Cypher recognizes csv files but do I have to create a csv file with my data or is there another way to import them ? Thank you for your help. Sam

Comment: Check out this material: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/blob/gh-pages/working-with-data/guide-importing-data-and-etl/guide-intro-to-import.adoc

Answer (score 1):

One option is to export your postgres data to csv and apply [LOAD CSV](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html) to import them into the graph.

Another way is writing a script in a language of choice (I'd vote for [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) here) that connects to Postgres using JDBC and connects to Neo4j and then applies the business logic to transform between the two.

A third option is using a ETL tool like Talend. It basically does the same as your custom script but provides a point & click interface to define the transformation, see http://neo4j.com/blog/fun-with-music-neo4j-and-talend/ for more details.

Comment: what about node or javascript?